# Simplest way to convert a property accessor expression to another that returns a more base type?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I have method that looks something like

```
ISomething<U> Foo<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> selector)
{
    Expression<Func<T, object>> generalSelector =
         ChangeSelectorReturnType<object>(selector);
    Use(generalSelector);
    return new Something<U>(selector);
}
```

What is the simplest code to implement `ChangeSelectorReturnType` assuming `selector` will always be a simple property accessor such as `x => x.Property`?

I know the solution [presented in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797261/mutating-the-expression-tree-of-a-predicate-to-target-another-type) works, but it requires a full expression visitor because no assumptions are made. I'm ok with assumptions in this case.

Comment: I think that the code accompanying this question is over-sanitized.  Where is the <T> generic specified?

Comment: Oh. It was actually on a containing interface, but I'll add it to the method just for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Convert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.convert.aspx) expression on the body of the lambda.  That will allow you to change its type.  Then recreate the lambda.

```
var modifiedBody = Expression.Convert(selector.Body, typeof(object));
var generalSelector =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(modifiedBody, selector.Parameters);
```