# Convert Expression<Func<TModel, IList<TItem>>> to Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable>>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, expression, enumerable

I have some method:

```
public void Foo(Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable>> expression) {
  // foo
}
```

and I have variable:

```
Expression<Func<TModel, IList<TItem>>> expression;
```

How I can pass my variable to `Foo`?

Comment: With **much** effort. See my own question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2797261/50079); read at the very least [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10467736/50079) (as the accepted one does not answer the most important part of your question) *and* the comments. I 'm not marking it as a dupe, leaving that for you to decide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert your expression variable:

```
var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, IEnumerable>>(expression.Body, expression.Parameters);
Foo(exp);
```

Comment: There will be InvalidCastException on casting to Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable>>. Without casting pass a LambdaExpression to Foo will cause compiler error.

Comment: @Dennis My solution doesn't use casting so it works without error.

Comment: My bad. I've missed using of generic overload `Expression.Lambda`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
    public Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable>> ConvertExpression<TModel, TItem>(Expression<Func<TModel, IList<TItem>>> expression)
    {
        return (Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable>>)Expression
            .Lambda(Expression.Convert(expression.Body, typeof(IEnumerable)), expression.Parameters);
    }
```