# Conversion of Expression Func types

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, expression, func

I have an

```
Expression<Func<T_ENTITY_A, object>> sortExpression
```

which I need to convert to a

```
Expression<Func<T_ENTITY_B, object>> sortExpression
```

Each property in T_ENTITY_A maps to another property in T_ENTITY_B, and I have a table which maps one property to another.  How would you go about implementing this?  I am assuming it will need to be done using reflection...

Comment: Is this expression used by EF or NH?

Comment: The expression will be used by EF

Comment: Are the property names exactly the same on both types?

Comment: Most probably yes - we can assume this to be the case for now :)

Comment: Check out this answer. It's dealing with the same problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10467736/2066026