# Convert Func<TDao, bool> to Func<TEntity, bool>

Tags: c#

Given:

```
class MyDao
{
   public int SiteId {get;set;}

   public Cv3AddressDao ReadSingle(Expression<Func<Cv3AddressDao, bool>> predicate)
   { //...
   }
}

class MyEntity
{
   public int SiteId {get;set;}
}
```

How can I take the predicate parameter of type `Expression<Func<MyDao, bool>>` and convert it to `Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>>`?

**The type of Answer I am looking for**

Please note that answers must show how conversion works.  I want an implementation similar to this but that works :)....

```
    public MyDao ReadSingle(Expression<Func<MyDao , bool>> predicate)
    {
        var mappedPredicate = MapFun<MyDao , MyEntity>(predicate);
        var result = repository.GetSingle<MyEntity>(mappedPredicate);

        return Convert(result);//Converts Entity to Dao...safe to ignore this line
    }

    Expression<Func<B, bool>> MapFun<A, B>(Expression<Func<A, bool>> input)
    {
        Expression<Func<B, bool>> result = null;//How to convert?
        return result;
    }
```

**Details regarding why I want this design...**

This is an asp.net MVC 5 application.  The reason this conversion is important is so my View is not aware of the type `MyEntity`.  In other words if I were to do:

`myDaoObject.ReadSingle<MyEntity>(myEntity => myEntity.SiteId == "123");`

Then my View layer has to reference my DLL layer because here I am using `MyEntity`.  I want the View layer to work with the Dao instead:

`myDaoObject.ReadSingle<MyDao>(myDao=> myDao.SiteId == "123");`

But, now I have to convert the Dao to make it useable with the Repository.  The Repository is only aware of DL objects.  I am trying to avoid creating a redundant Repository just to support this translation.  The DAO contains all the properties of the Entity plus some.

Comment: can you show us what you have investigated and tried?

Comment: @Default - Question updated with an implementation close to what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the exact code handy, but you will probably want to consume the expression provided and perform the equivalency conversion yourself.

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797261/mutating-the-expression-tree-of-a-predicate-to-target-another-type) is along the lines of what I would do.

**Note from P.Brian.Mackey**

The referred to answer worked.  Using Jon's answer does the trick.  However, the public portion of the answer ended up being a non-visible player for `Func<>` conversion.  All I needed was:

```
    Expression<Func<B, bool>> MapFun<A, B>(Expression<Func<A, bool>> input)where A : class
    {
        var result = DbAccessLayer.TransformPredicateLambda<A,B>(input);
        return result;
    }
```

Note that this method was private.  I changed it to public.  See @Jon answer in the answer referenced above for the full implementation.

```
public static Expression<Func<TNewTarget, bool>> TransformPredicateLambda<TOldTarget, TNewTarget>(Expression<Func<TOldTarget, bool>> predicate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have them share a common interface:

```
public interface ISited {
    int SiteId {get; set; }
}

class MyDao : ISited { .. }
class MyEntity : ISited { .. }
```

and use the common interface as a constraint on the generic type parameter in place of `C3VAddressDao`:

```
 public ISited ReadSingle(Expression<Func<ISited, bool>> predicate)
```

Of course, this might not be that useful without other common members that you would include in `ISited`.

Comment: This is a good idea, but in trying it I found that because I use `DbContext.Set<TEntity>()` in the repository I can't use this.  I need to convert between Func<>'s or do something else entirely if that is not possible.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, I am also stuck in the same problem, can you please help me, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884451/convert-expressionfunct-bool-to-another-predicate-expression-expressionfun)

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass it in

```
public Cv3AddressDao ReadSingle<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    // ...
}
...
var dao = new MyDao();
var addr = dao.ReadSingle<MyEntity>(x => x.SiteId == 1);
```

Comment: This would result in coupling my View layer to my data layer.  The point of the Dao is so I don't have this coupling.  Even with the update it requires that the lamba is defined in the View.  I don't see how this will work.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey you make no mention of layers in your question, maybe you should update your question so it's *clear* what your requirements are. Until you detail your app architecture it's difficult to revise my answer.

Comment: I updated the question.  Hopefully that will clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Expression<Func<B, bool>> MapFun<A, B>(Expression<Func<A, bool>> input) where A : class
    {
        return b => input.Compile()((b as A));
    }
```

that should work for you because you're just converting the parameter.

update:

based on your updated answer you have a couple options.

Use reflection to copy values from the entity to the DAO (look at something like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper))

the other option you have is to define a custom conversion between your 2 types using something like IConvertable.

Comment: Ugh so close...Runtime error:  `No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Boolean' and 'MvcApplication1.Models.MyEntity'.`

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey edited my answer, basicly you want to call input with B instead of type A, so you'll need to cast B to A, constraint added due to compile time error.

Comment: Different runtime error:  `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`  I'm having TFS trouble all the sudden.  Gonna have to table this for a bit...

Comment: I've never dealt with LINQ to Entities so I cant say. I would ask why you're writing an expression that expects a MyDao but then you're calling a method that will pass in a MyEntity, just write your expression to expect MyEntity instead.