# Is it possible to convert Expression<Func<T, bool>> to Expression<Func<MyType, bool>>?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda

I have a repository class with some generic methods. One is

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindAll<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
{
    return GetDbSet<T>().Where(predicate);
}
```

For unit testing I have a `TestRepository` which uses in-memory objects instead of a database. The `TestRepository` overrides the `FindAll` method and I want to control what is returned. So I want to be able to do something like this:

```
public override IEnumerable<T> FindAll<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return MyEntities.Where(predicate).Cast<T>();
}
```

But `MyEntities.Where()` only accepts a `Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>>`.

How can I cast/convert the generic expression to the strongly typed expression?

Comment: Have you thought about mocking your repository instead?

Comment: @JakubKonecki: Isn't that exactly what he is doing here?

Comment: @Jon - no, he's stubbing not mocking.

Comment: Reading about [Covariance & Contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) might help.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: Or it might not. No relation to this case.

Comment: @NicklasJepsen: I asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2797261/50079) some time ago, which you will find interesting.

Comment: @Jon, how not related? It's like the [`Liskove's substitution principle`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) here. If you can accept type A, then you should be able to accept subtypes of A too. He can extend his `MyEntities` and all other `Entity` classes he has, and pass those derived types to the expression. Am I incorrect?

Comment: @Jon, I have thought about mocking as a solution for this specific case. But isn't it possible to make this conversion?
I will read the question you linked to and see if I will change my mind.

Comment: @Grundy: A Collection of MyEntity.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: Variance in C# is only applicable to generic interfaces and delegates. `Expression<T>` is neither, so variance does not apply here.

Comment: you can try this `return MyEntities.Cast<T>().Where(predicate);`

Comment: @NicklasJepsen: It is possible, if I 'm not mistaken you have the same problem as I did with the difference that in my case the `T` was fixed -- which does not change anything when talking about expression trees.

Comment: @Grundy: That is exactly what I did try. Did you read the question?

Comment: in my comment before `cast` and then `where` in your - vice versa

Comment: @Grundy: I'm sorry, I didn't read your comment.. Will try some solutions from these comments and return with the result.

Comment: @NicklasJepsen: Grundy's approach would work, at least on the surface: `return MyEntities.Cast<T>().AsQueryable().Where(predicate);`. But that raises the question, what exactly would that be testing?

Comment: @Jon test will be work if `T` is `MyEntity` :-)

Comment: @Jon: Your attempted solution in the post you refer to actually does work for me.

Comment: @NicklasJepsen: That solution is "hardcore" in the sense that it maintains the `IQueryable` property of your alternate data source. It looks like you don't need that here, so Grundy's would be much easier to use. It loses queryability, but do you care?

Comment: @Jon: If I try Grundy's solution I get: 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. Not sure whether it's a good idea, but it works. Basically, your overload can compare the type parameter `T` to your entity class. If the predicate has the right type, you can cast. Otherwise, you don't have anything to return.

```
public class MyEntity { public int x; }

MyEntity[] MyEntitiesList = Enumerable.Range(1,5).Select(y => new MyEntity() { x = y }).ToArray();

public IEnumerable<T> FindAll<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
     if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyEntity))
     {
         return (IEnumerable<T>)MyEntitiesList.Where((predicate as Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>>).Compile());
     }
     return new T[0];
}
```

---

Usage:

```
var res = FindAll((MyEntity y) => y.x % 2 == 0).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(res.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your repository implementation has a major flaw in a sense that the caller is not aware that he can only pass arguments of certain types (e.g. it looks like I can do `FindAll<int>(v => v > 0)` but in fact, the underlying implementation only works with `MyEntity`). In other words, it's trying to be too "smart", it's not intuitive and error-prone.

One way of fixing this can be by introducing an interface/base class:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
  IEnumerable<T> FindAll<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
}

// A base class that can carry helper functionality.
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
  private readonly IEnumerable<T> _entities;

  protected Repository(IEnumerable<T> entities)
  {
    _entities = entities;
  }

  public IEnumerable<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
  {
    return _entities.Where(predicate);
  }
}

// Concrete implementation
public class MyEntityRepository : Repository<MyEntity>
{
  public MyEntityRepository() : base(new MyDbContext().MyEntities) { }
}
```

In the above example I'm referring to `MyDbContext` just for demonstration purposes (so it looks a bit more familiar if you worked with [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)).

Now you can instantiate `MyEntityRepository` and use it throughout the application. In case you're using some sort of IoC, you can modify the code slightly:

```
public interface IMyEntityRepository : IRepository<MyEntity>
{
  // ...
}

public class MyEntityRepository : Repository<MyEntity>, IMyEntityRepository
{
  // ...
}
```

And now you can easily inject and mock `IMyEntityRepository` within your application.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

As it turns out, since the given implementation is used for testing purposes only, you could try producing the expression of a desired type the following way:

```
return MyEntities.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<MyEntity, bool>>(predicate.Body, 
  predicate.Parameters)).Cast<T>();
```

You can also apply some casting to the lambda parameter, if explicit one is needed.

Comment: The implemented repository is only used for unit testing. I have a completely generic repository which I use to query the database. When not running the tests, all types are accepted.

Comment: I don't think this is the way to go for me because I do not want to have a repository for each different entity type.

Comment: @NicklasJepsen Are you referring to the last paragraph with `Expression.Lambda`? I left the first part in case someone with similar issues might want to consider using the approach I provided (by the way, we widely use it in our current project and it has proven to be quite flexible and maintainable).