# Is there an inverse operation to Expression.Lambda?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

Is there an inverse operation to `Expression.Lambda<...>(originalExpression, parameterExpression)` that would return me the original expression?

Context:

I am creating a lambda expression using the lambda syntax (not using the Expression class at all) like this:

```
 return item => item.Something
```

In a different layer of the application, I would like to "un-lambda" this expression, apply

```
expression= Expression.Not(expression);
```

to it and then wrap it to a lambda again.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`LambdaExpression.Body`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.body%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is your original expression, so you can do

```
var inverted = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Not(lambda.Body), lambda.Parameters);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling with the parameters, I was passing a new ParameterExpression (same count and types of arguments) in the Lambda call and apparently I have to pass in the very same instance of parameters that the lambda was using.

Comment: @TomasGrosup: [I had that problem myself](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2797261/50079) in the past ;-)